Struggling with detecting a moving/animated icon using template matching
I'm trying to detect a small icon that moves using OpenCV. I've followed several tutorials that use matchTemplate(), but it's not working as well as I hoped. Sometimes it detects the icon, but other times it completely misses it, especially when the icon is moving faster, stops, or looks a bit different such as shining or moving its tail.
I've tried different thresholds and converting the frames to grayscale, but it either detects something else or doesn't detect the icon at all (please check the video below).
How can I improve my logic to detect the icon consistently? Do I need a better icon?
I'm testing my logic with a video, but it will be used in real-time by capturing game's window.
template = cv2.imread("assets/icon.png")
threshold = 0.6

def video_player():
    if not cap.isOpened():
        print("Couldn't open video")
        sleep(3)
        exit()

    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        frame_copy = frame

        if not ret:
            print("Reached the end of the video.")
            sleep(3)
            cap.release()
            cv2.destroyAllWindows()
            break

        result = cv2.matchTemplate(frame_copy, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)
        print(max_val)

        if max_val >= threshold:
            top_left = max_loc
            h, w = template.shape[:2]
            bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

            cv2.rectangle(frame_copy, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.imshow('Video', frame_copy)

        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

Icon: 
Output:


Your icon is transparent. But when you read it, you read only the BGR channels, which have a white background.  That will not match well to the dark background or colored background in the image.  What you should do, is read the image unchanged to get the alpha channel. Then separate the base image and the alpha channel. Then use the BGR channel base image as the template and use the alpha channel as a mask in matchTemplate so that the background area is not used in the matching. Search this forum. There are numerous examples that I have posted showing how to do this.

See the docs for matchTemplate to see that is permits the use of a mask. There is a mask parameter for it.

everyone uses "suboptimal" (bad) matching modes for their game cheats... and that & 0xFF has been literally redundant for eight years

@fmw42 thanks. I will try your suggestions and update the question

@ChristophRackwitz how can I improve myself to learn the best matching modes? I appreciate your suggestions

One way is that when you get it working, try the different matching modes to see which ones are best. Check the docs for matchTemplate. Not all modes permit a mask depending upon OpenCV version.

If you read the documentation for matchTemplate (for the most current version of OpenCV) it says: "..., the best matches can be found as global minimums (when TM_SQDIFF was used) or maximums (when TM_CCORR or TM_CCOEFF was used) using the minMaxLoc function".  One missing piece of information is that it does not explain what is I' (vs I) or I have missed it. I prefer the normed versions as it is easier to find maximums or ranges and thus thresholds.

that bias towards maxima (CCOEFF, CCORR) and normalization (NORMED), giving percentage/"confidence", handicaps people. we've had a similar question on matchTemplate recently. OP refused to consider the SQDIFF modes, claiming the "minimum" thing is weird or something. OP refused to let go of a mode (normed even) that literally caused inf/nan on his data. that mindset of "I need help but I also know what I'm doing" made progress impossible. instead of just trying my suggestions, they needed something close to a mathematical proof that their approach wasn't just suboptimal but plain unworkable.

@Christoph Rackwitz Interesting case!  What application or situation caused inf/nan on a normalized (cross correlation)?  By the way the docs do not explain what is I' (vs I) in the matching modes (i.e. the difference between CCOEFF, CCORR) or have I missed it?

quoting pieces from elsewhere... all the “normed” modes involve a division (see docs). if that term happens to be zero for some reason, you get inf/nan. that happens when the haystack in a particular area or needle are exactly black. “normed” modes sound convenient but they really aren’t. “confidence” is generally a nebulous term. image patch differences could be quantified as a histogram or cumulative distribution. then you could say, “what fraction of pixels differs by at least some threshold”.
